# Variable "userQuestion" does not have a value. I am attempting to access it from another class, but it does not return anything

Tags: java, user-interface, variables, scope

The class where I declared and set the variable.
The variable userQuestion is being set each time the user activates a button.  The purpose is so that it can be used in the next class to reask that question.  However, it seems like the userQuestion variable is not being set.  Sorry for the messy code, it was made using Window Builder in Eclipse.

https://pastebin.com/azP6SbRa

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.Insets;


public class createprojecte extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField textField;
private JButton btnWhatIsYour;
private JButton btnWhereDidYour;
private JButton btnWhatWasThe;
private JButton btnWhoIsYour;
private JButton btnWhatIsYour_1;
private JButton btnWhatIsYour_2;



public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                createprojecte frame = new createprojecte();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    })
    ;
}

String userQuestion;

public createprojecte() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    GridBagLayout gbl_contentPane = new GridBagLayout();
    gbl_contentPane.columnWidths = new int[]{424, 0};
    gbl_contentPane.rowHeights = new int[]{20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    gbl_contentPane.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    gbl_contentPane.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    contentPane.setLayout(gbl_contentPane);

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setText("Choose what security option you want:");
    textField.setColumns(10);
    GridBagConstraints gbc_textField = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_textField.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_textField.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
    gbc_textField.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_textField.gridx = 0;
    gbc_textField.gridy = 0;
    contentPane.add(textField, gbc_textField);


    btnWhatIsYour = new JButton("What is your mother's maiden name?");
    btnWhatIsYour.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            input frame = new input();
            frame.setVisible(true);
            String userQuestion = "What is your mother's maiden name?";
            frame.SetUserQuestion(userQuestion);
        }
    });
    GridBagConstraints gbc_btnWhatIsYour = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_btnWhatIsYour.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_btnWhatIsYour.gridx = 0;
    gbc_btnWhatIsYour.gridy = 2;
    contentPane.add(btnWhatIsYour, gbc_btnWhatIsYour);

    btnWhereDidYour = new JButton("Where did your parents meet?");
    btnWhereDidYour.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            input frame = new input();
            frame.setVisible(true);
            String userQuestion = "Where did your parents meet?";

        }
    });
    GridBagConstraints gbc_btnWhereDidYour = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_btnWhereDidYour.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_btnWhereDidYour.gridx = 0;
    gbc_btnWhereDidYour.gridy = 3;
    contentPane.add(btnWhereDidYour, gbc_btnWhereDidYour);

    btnWhatWasThe = new JButton("What was the first street you lived on?");
    btnWhatWasThe.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            input frame = new input();
            frame.setVisible(true);
            String userQuestion = "What was the first street you lived on?";
        }
    });
    GridBagConstraints gbc_btnWhatWasThe = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_btnWhatWasThe.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_btnWhatWasThe.gridx = 0;
    gbc_btnWhatWasThe.gridy = 4;
    contentPane.add(btnWhatWasThe, gbc_btnWhatWasThe);

    btnWhoIsYour = new JButton("Who is your favorite music group?");
    btnWhoIsYour.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            input frame = new input();
            frame.setVisible(true);
            String userQuestion = "Who is your favorite music group?";
        }
    });
    GridBagConstraints gbc_btnWhoIsYour = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_btnWhoIsYour.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_btnWhoIsYour.gridx = 0;
    gbc_btnWhoIsYour.gridy = 5;
    contentPane.add(btnWhoIsYour, gbc_btnWhoIsYour);

    btnWhatIsYour_1 = new JButton("What is your favorite book?");
    btnWhatIsYour_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            input frame = new input();
            frame.setVisible(true);
            String userQuestion = "What is your favorite book?";
        }
    });
    GridBagConstraints gbc_btnWhatIsYour_1 = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_btnWhatIsYour_1.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_btnWhatIsYour_1.gridx = 0;
    gbc_btnWhatIsYour_1.gridy = 6;
    contentPane.add(btnWhatIsYour_1, gbc_btnWhatIsYour_1);

    btnWhatIsYour_2 = new JButton("What is your favorite sports team?");
    btnWhatIsYour_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            input frame = new input();
            frame.setVisible(true);
            String userQuestion = "What is your favorite sports team?";
        }
    });
    GridBagConstraints gbc_btnWhatIsYour_2 = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_btnWhatIsYour_2.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_btnWhatIsYour_2.gridx = 0;
    gbc_btnWhatIsYour_2.gridy = 7;
    contentPane.add(btnWhatIsYour_2, gbc_btnWhatIsYour_2);
}
}
```

The class where I am trying to access the variable.
https://pastebin.com/vb6MWeba

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import java.awt.Insets;

public class input extends JFrame {
private JTextField txtWhatIsThe;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */ 
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                input frame = new input();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
String userQuestion;

public void SetUserQuestion(String question)
{
    this.userQuestion = question;
}

public input() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
    gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0};
    gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0};
    gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    getContentPane().setLayout(gridBagLayout);

    txtWhatIsThe = new JTextField();
    txtWhatIsThe.setText(userQuestion );
    GridBagConstraints gbc_txtWhatIsThe = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_txtWhatIsThe.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_txtWhatIsThe.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_txtWhatIsThe.gridx = 0;
    gbc_txtWhatIsThe.gridy = 0;
    getContentPane().add(txtWhatIsThe, gbc_txtWhatIsThe);
    txtWhatIsThe.setColumns(10);
}

}
```

Comment: Better if you paste exactly the code INTO the question here. Nobody wants to read your pastebin links.

Comment: Better yet, don't paste *all* the code - paste a [mcve].

Comment: (Now would be a good time to learn about and start following Java naming conventions, too.)

Answer (score 0):

You are not really setting your questions into the frame in some of your listeners:

```
btnWhatIsYour_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        input frame = new input();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        String userQuestion = "What is your favorite book?";
        // Missing setter
    }
});
```

Comment: What method would I use? Would I use a method in the JFrame or the ActionListener?

Comment: frame.SetUserQuestion(userQuestion); as you do in your first listener

Comment: I tried that but it still returns null in the new window that is opened.